# How to reduce memory consumption of docker containers?

Tags: mysql, memory, docker

I run a golang container and a mysql container on a Vultr VPS with memory of 768M. They are built from official images without much further work yet. And the 767M memory is not enough with the error of "fatal error: runtime: out of memory".

(1) This is normal? The only solution is to increase the VPS memory?
(2) This is abnormal? I should do certain settings to control or reduce the memory consumption?
(3) What will happen if it reaches memory upper limit, if I use --memory="" to control the memory consumption?

Comment: maybe you can have smaller images, built from alpine instead of ubuntu or debian? can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: @user2915097 while lower image size is nice it doesn't have any impact on memory usage.

Comment: Is this really related to Docker? Does the application consume much less memory when run outside of a container?

Comment: I use golang:1.6rc2 and mysql:5.7  to run two containers directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the memory of the container itself, however it will only cause the error to occur sooner as less memory will be available. Do you know which one of your containers is consuming the majority of the memory?

Comment: mysql costs quite a lot of memory

Comment: I do not believe the memory consumption is related to your Docker containers in that case.  How large is your database?  What version of MySQL are you using?  Have you configured your mysql installation to limit its memory usage?

Comment: A brandnew database with nothing. Iuse mysql5.7. I don't configure for memory limit. Can I do something to reduce the mysql's consumption.